# What layout should i use for galaxy note 10.1 2014 edition?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I am using sw720-layout  for galaxy tab3 10.1(~149 PPI) & for phone i am using xhpi-layout for Galaxy s3(~306 PPI). I want to know which layout folder should i use for Galaxy Note 10.1 2014 edition(~299 PPI) so that my previous layout does not affect.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest not thinking about specific devices, but use buckets instead: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html . A fast way to learn it is by creating a new Android project, inside the wizard itself. Another way is to check tutorials about Fragments .

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use **xlarge-xhdpi-layout** for Galaxy Note 2014 specific layout, but as it's was said in comment you should prefer a buckets approach.